# Incrementing a variable triggers EXIT in bash 4, but not in bash 3

Tags: bash, version, exit, increment

Consider this (exemplary) bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
errorExit() {
    echo "" >&2
    echo "ERROR (${var_scriptfilename}):" >&2
    echo "An unhandled error occurred." >&2
    intentionalExit 1
}
intentionalExit () {
    trap - EXIT # Unregister the EXIT trap
    exit $1
}
trap errorExit EXIT # Trap script errors
var_scriptfilename="$(basename "$0")"
# ==== START OF TEST ====
var_counter=0
((var_counter++))
echo "var_counter is $var_counter" >&2
# ===== END OF TEST =====
intentionalExit 0
```

If I run it in Cygwin's bash it produces the intended output:

```
var_counter is 1
```

However, if I run it on my Debian Squeeze box, which is its intended destination, I end up in the EXIT trap:

```
ERROR (test.increment.sh):
An unhandled error occurred.
```

...Why is that?

If I remove the -e option it works as expected on both systems, but I want to keep -e in use, obviously.

The slightly more cumbersome "universal" variant, `var_counter=$(($var_counter+1))`, works with -e being set on both shells, but I would prefer to use the first notation (or something similar-looking) since it clearly sticks out as an increment operation when reading the code.

`bash --version` on the Cygwin bash says:

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(24)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

On Debian, it is:

```
GNU bash, Version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I am intrigued as to why this is that way. Does anybody know the cause of this behavior?

Also, does anybody know of a similar-looking way to increment a variable in bash that I could use?

Comment: do you see anything helpful when you `set -vx` ? Good Luck.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the bash4 manpage on Debian:

```
((expression))
    The expression is evaluated according  to  the  rules  described
    below  under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If the value of the expres‐
    sion is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise  the  return
    status is 1.  This is exactly equivalent to let "expression".
```

and also ...

```
-e      Exit  immediately  if a pipeline (which may consist of a
        single simple command),  a subshell command enclosed  in
        parentheses,  or one of the commands executed as part of
        a command list enclosed by  braces  (see  SHELL  GRAMMAR
        above) exits with a non-zero status.
```

So what is happening is `((var++))` increments var from 0 to 1 and returns 
0, causing the overall expression to return non-zero, which triggers 
`errexit`.

Now for the difference between the two different bash versions: this change 
in `((` behavior seems to have occurred between 4.0 and 4.1.  In 4.0 `((` 
apparently did not trigger errexit.  See this [NEWS](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) file for the details.
You'll have to scroll down to line 135 or so.  The Changelog from the source
distribution seems to confirm this.

If you just want a variable incremented without using the exit status, 
there's multiple ways to do it.  Maybe some other people could give advice 
on which is the best, but some possibilities are:

- `var="$((var+1))"`, the portable POSIX `sh` method
- `((var++)) || true`, forcing the statement to always have a zero 
  exit status (bash only)

Comment: Thank you very much, that surely sheds a lot of light on that one. I figure, seeing that EXIT is only called because I start counting from 0 on, I can use pre-increment instead of post-increment, i.e. `((++var_counter))` instead of `((var_counter++))`. The results of the calculation then start at 1 and the return value will always be zero. I have successfully tested this on both of the mentioned shells now.

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez `(( ))` is a standalone command, like executing a statement in other programming languages.  `(( 2 + 2 ))` would just run, returning 0 to the shell.  `$(( ))` is an expansion - the results of the expression are inserted back into the command line in place of the `$(( ))` expression.  It is usually used as part of a longer command line.